# ExpressJS request body suddenly modified with nested object in Node 18

Tags: node.js, express, google-kubernetes-engine

I experienced this strange issue when working with ExpressJS using Node 18 deployed on GKE.

This issue happened after I upgraded the Node version to 18, prev was in 14 and all was fine.

I have a POST request to one of my API with the following body

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "http://some-url",
    "name": "some name"
  }
}
```

I added datadog logger right after the request entered the controller function and it showed like this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "http://some-url",
    "name": "some name",
    "data": {
      "url": "http://some-url",
      "name": "some name"
    }
  }
}
```

Suddenly it contains a nested object, I do not have any middleware in it, except Swagger but it should not be the issue.

The issue didn't happen on Local, only happened in GKE after a Node upgrade to 18, prev was fine.

The issue also does not always happen, but frequently, sometimes it logs the correct req body.

Here is my node app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import swaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-express';
import yaml from 'yamljs';

import errorMiddleware from './middlewares/error.middleware';
import { validator, validatorHandler } from './middlewares/open_api_validator';
import routes from './routes/routes';

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const swaggerJsDocs = yaml.load(path.resolve(__dirname, '../api.yaml'));
app.use('/docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerJsDocs));
app.use(validator(), validatorHandler);

app.use('/', routes);
```

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as OpenApiValidator from 'express-openapi-validator';
import path from 'path';

export const validator = () =>
  OpenApiValidator.middleware({
    apiSpec: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../api.yaml'),
    validateRequests: false
  });

export const validatorHandler = (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  err.api_error_code = 'SC1050D';

  next(err);
};
```

Version

```
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-openapi-validator": "^4.13.8",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.7",
```

What's wrong with it, since it was working fine before Node and package update.